# insert csv into phpMyAdmin and skip columns

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv that looks like this

```
DETAIL,CARDMT,67145,20160102,0571008,30900,ID22,1,C,44.70,A,44.70,A,20160101,20170124
DETAIL,CARDMT,67145,20160102,0571031,18309,FGIPA46C,1,C,29.50,A,29.50,A,20160101,20170124
```

I only need the 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 columns

I tried

```
,dist_abbv,,date, invoice, account_vip_id, brand, quantity,,,,,,,,
```

so it skips the columns I dont need with a space and the location of the ones I do need go into the right column in my table but I get the error:

```
Invalid column () specified! Ensure that columns names are spelled correctly, separated by commas, and not enclosed in quotes.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have the same necessity, but seems nobody can help me!